# Validation won't run. I get an 'Uncaught Type Error' from the addEventListener

Tags: null

I keep getting an 'Uncaught Type Error' (null) when I try to run this validation. I've logged out the variable 'submitEl' but I keep getting null. Is that correct? It won't run through.

```
    <div class='form-actions-container call-to-action'>
            <button id='submit-el' class='colored button FormBtn' 
            type='submit'>SUBMIT</button>
    </div>
    <div class="alertMessage">
            <h2 class="fill_text">PLEASE FILL OUT ALL QUESTIONS.</h2> 
            <h3 class="fill_text">Thank you.</h3>

    </div>

    const option = document.getElementsByName(
    'pending_subscriber[custom_fields][302]');
    let submitEl = document.getElementById('submit-el');

    const error = document.getElementsByClassName('alertMessage');

    submitEl.addEventListener('click', function () {
    if (!(option[0].checked || option[1].checked)) {
        error.style.display = 'block';
        return false;
    }
    });
```

Comment: Looks like I got rid of that error by putting defer in the script src, but now erroring out on the 'error.style.display' line (Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'display'))

Comment: figured it out. Looks like the h2 and h3 tags were screwing it up. I deleted the tags and style with css. Now my validation code works.